# coding in c on eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

The code below prints out "Enter an integer: " after I input an integer. I'm coding this In C on Eclipse, and I know this is a newbie question, but can someone tell me why this is?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Enter an integer: \n");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   if ( n%2 == 0 )
      printf("Even\n");
   else
      printf("Odd\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How _exactly_ are you running this program? When run from a terminal directly, I get the prompt before I input a number, exactly as you (and I) expect.

Comment: Try putting `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf` statement

Comment: try fflush(stdout); after the printf.  Seems like it may be getting buffered.

Comment: I/O should be buffered but flushed after every newline, so your case should be ok (you print `\n` after the prompt). However, for some reason, this didn't happen. As @sarnold pointed out, this is an unusual behavior for a terminal, so... how do you run it?

Comment: @Imp: Exactly -- I'm wondering if it is being executed in a poor terminal _replacement_ tool that uses pipes for IO...

Comment: i build the binary file by using CTRL-B, and then i run it. it doesn't output anything until i enter an integer in the console. then it prints out everything. and one more question guys.. is it possible to download a program called "Terminal" on PC? "Terminal" is the program we use in class to code in C, and as far as I know, only Macs use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can not read integer value in Eclipse 
try this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int n;
   printf("Enter an integer: \n");
   fflush( stdout );
   scanf("%d",&n);
   if ( n%2 == 0 )
      printf("Even\n");
   else
  printf("Odd\n");
  return 0;
```

}